# Appending query help for access?

Tags: ms-access, duplicates, append

I have a general question about Microsoft access append queries.
Heres the background of what Im trying to do, We have a online database with contact information on people that I pull down monthly via a excel file. I import it in to a table and now I'm trying to append that into a table that contains not only the fields in the table but a few more with certification dates.

Now, my question is, how can I have the append query check that the record im bringing in is the same person as the one on the original, and have it overwrite without any changes. Is that just how a append query works or does it it require some coding to make it do that?

tl;dr? Append query, how do I make it not overwrite over the wrong records?

I've had no formal education and Its been hard to find data on the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append queries do not check for matches or duplicates. Append queries append new records, but do not append new data to existing records.

For what you have there I recommend using VBA. I think it would be simplest to use ADO to open a recordset based on the excel sheet, and then use DLookup or DCount to see if a matching record already exists before performing the insert or update statement.

Comment: Decided to use a Update query instead, but thanks for steering me away from append.